# How to only allow a node to be viewed in its assigned language?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I have three languages on my site:

```
/en
/es
```

If I have a node with ID = 1234 and this node in english, then I can view it as follows:

```
/en/node/1234
```

And this will redirect to

```
/en/my-page
```

Which is great! The problem is, if I view this ENGLISH page from another language. I.e. If I open this:

```
/es/node/1234
```

Then it opens the english page but the link remains at /es/node/1234

I enabled the "[Translation Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/node/1280468)" module, but this doesn't do exactly what I was hoping it would do. In the above case, if you open:

```
/en/node/1234
```

And there IS a "ES" version of the page, it will redirect to that page. Which is great, except sometimes I have a page that does not have a translation, and in the case I want that link to redirect to the correct page. In other words, opening this:

```
/es/node/1234
```

Must take you to:

```
/en/node/1234
```

Which will then automatically take you to:

```
/en/my-page
```

Is there a way to enable this in i18n or must I write something custom to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i18n_redirect module has simple code, so turn it off, and add next code to custom module:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_init()
 */
function CUSTOMMODULE_init() {

    $path = $_GET['q'];
    $language = i18n_language_interface();
    // Not for logged in users nor for home page
    if (!$path || drupal_is_front_page() || !empty($GLOBALS['user']->uid)) {
        return;
    }
    elseif ($translations = i18n_get_path_translations($path)) {
        if (isset($translations[$language->language]) && $translations[$language->language]['href'] != $path) {
            drupal_goto($translations[$language->language]['href'], array('language' => $language), 301);
        }
        else {
            // Here we working with node, since question about node redirections
            $node = menu_get_object();
            if ($node && $node->language && ($node->language != $language->language)) {
                $languages = language_list();
                if (isset($languages[$node->language])) {
                    $language = $languages[$node->language];
                    drupal_goto('node/' . $node->nid, array('language' => $language), 301);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```